# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, pyarrow

I am trying to run a simple pandas UDF example on my server. From [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#scalar)

I have created a fresh environment just for the purpose of running this code.

```
(PySparkEnv) $ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
arrow-cpp                 0.10.0           py36h70250a7_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
boost-cpp                 1.67.0               h3a22d5f_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.6                h470a237_2    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2018.8.24            ha4d7672_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2018.8.24                py36_1    conda-forge
icu                       58.2                 hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.0                      117  
libffi                    3.2.1                hfc679d8_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                hdf63c60_3    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            7.2.0                hdf63c60_3    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              7.2.0                hdf63c60_3    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.0                      117  
mkl_fft                   1.0.6                    py36_0    conda-forge
mkl_random                1.0.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1                  hfc679d8_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.15.0           py36h1b885b7_0  
numpy-base                1.15.0           py36h3dfced4_0  
openssl                   1.0.2p               h470a237_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.23.4           py36hf8a1672_0    conda-forge
parquet-cpp               1.5.0.pre            h83d4a3d_0    conda-forge
pip                       18.0                     py36_1    conda-forge
py4j                      0.10.7                     py_1    conda-forge
pyarrow                   0.10.0           py36hfc679d8_0    conda-forge
pyspark                   2.3.1                    py36_1    conda-forge
python                    3.6.6                h5001a0f_0    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.7.3                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2018.5                     py_0    conda-forge
readline                  7.0                  haf1bffa_1    conda-forge
setuptools                40.2.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
six                       1.11.0                   py36_1    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.24.0               h2f33b56_1    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.8                         0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_1    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4                h470a237_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               h470a237_3    conda-forge
```

Then I run the following code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import pandas as pd
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python3'
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '30g')
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.cores', '5')
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example").getOrCreate()

# Declare the function and create the UDF
def multiply_func(a, b):
    return a * b

multiply = pandas_udf(multiply_func, returnType=LongType())

# The function for a pandas_udf should be able to execute with local Pandas data
x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
print(multiply_func(x, x))
# 0    1
# 1    4
# 2    9
# dtype: int64

# Create a Spark DataFrame, 'spark' is an existing SparkSession
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["x"]))

# Execute function as a Spark vectorized UDF
df.select(multiply(col("x"), col("x"))).show()
```

I am getting the following error which I am unable to find help on.

```
ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 219, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 139, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 127, in read_single_udf
    return arg_offsets, wrap_scalar_pandas_udf(row_func, return_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in wrap_scalar_pandas_udf
    arrow_return_type = to_arrow_type(return_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1613, in to_arrow_type
    import pyarrow as pa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.<init>(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-13 11:55:39 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 219, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 139, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 127, in read_single_udf
    return arg_offsets, wrap_scalar_pandas_udf(row_func, return_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in wrap_scalar_pandas_udf
    arrow_return_type = to_arrow_type(return_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1613, in to_arrow_type
    import pyarrow as pa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.<init>(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018-09-13 11:55:39 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 350, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 219, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 139, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 127, in read_single_udf
    return arg_offsets, wrap_scalar_pandas_udf(row_func, return_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in wrap_scalar_pandas_udf
    arrow_return_type = to_arrow_type(return_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1613, in to_arrow_type
    import pyarrow as pa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.<init>(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1602)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1823)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1772)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1761)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 219, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 139, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 127, in read_single_udf
    return arg_offsets, wrap_scalar_pandas_udf(row_func, return_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in wrap_scalar_pandas_udf
    arrow_return_type = to_arrow_type(return_type)
  File "/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1613, in to_arrow_type
    import pyarrow as pa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.<init>(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

More importantly, this works on my local machine. 
Will be grateful for any help that I can get on this. I have been stuck for a couple of days now.

Comment: Just curious what `which python` returns?

Comment: ~/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/bin/python

Comment: Can you do `import pyarrow as pa` from a python environment?

Comment: import pyarrow works.
>>> import pyarrow as pa
/home/shekhar/.conda/envs/PySparkEnv/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds)

Comment: Then it's beyond me, I'm afraid. You could try uninstalling and reinstalling stuff on your server.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem in a AWS EMR. I tried the other answers but they didn't work.

The only solution worked for me was install `pyarrow` with pip instead `conda`.

```
pip install pyarrow
```

I really don't know why, but it can be useful if you have same problem.

Comment: For me this works. I do not understand why this works. I was running my  application in a virtual envinroment using Anaconda, but after pip install pyarrow, everything works fine.

Comment: I had same problem with Python 3.10 and  pyarrow 9.0.0.  I  tried deleting the ```__pycache__``` files as proposed below, and it didnt work. I tried both intel and conda-forge channels and neither worked: ```pyarrow``` would show as an installed package but ```import pyarrow`` always failed. But pip. Worked straight away. [And Yes, I dont understand either]

Answer (score 4):

Delete your `__pycache__` files.

I had exactly the same problem and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue for the jupyter notebook attached to AWS EMR. Installing `pyarrow` only on master node didn't work. Then I installed both `pandas` and `pyarrow` in the core nodes as well, and the error went away.

Comment: Hi, I think this would solve my problem as well. Would you mind telling me more about core node, and how would I install my pyarrow in that core node? Pandas is working in Jupyter notebook, but pyarrow gives me the same error all the time: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow''' when I ran pip3 install pyarrow and even done it with brew :brew install apache-arrow" The requrements already have been satisfied. So I'm kinda lost. I need to import this library to my J. notebook.

Comment: A bootstrap script is most likely going to solve the issue you're facing. Please check my answer here: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/57408712/4245859`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install pyarrow in command prompt with the command 'pip install pyarrow', but it didn't work for me.

### Solution

This has worked:

- Open the Anaconda Navigator, launch CMD.exe prompt,
- Write `pip install pyarrow`. I got the message

```
Installing collected packages: pyarrow
Successfully installed pyarrow-10.0.0
```

Finally, I can use `pd.read_parquet('file name')`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved the problem? Which IDE were you using?

In case you were using an IDE, you should install the IDE in the conda environment and use it from there.

Comment: If you have any questions then those can be asked in comments. Try avoiding asking many questions in your answer and giving solution on the basis of guess.

Comment: Do not remember how I solved it. But maybe there should be a warning message highlighting that an IDE version is not installed.

Comment: For the IDE issue there is no warning message, would be nice to have one through. As one just activated the IDE in the general settings but not from the conda environment, some of the packages have problems, like pyarrow and tqdm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you has a directory called Pyarrow in you project directore tree.

Answer (score 0):

You should install  Datasets in a virtual environment to keep things tidy and avoid dependency conflicts.

a link is here: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/en/installation