# AWS EMR - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am running into this problem w/ Apache Arrow Spark Integration.

Using AWS EMR w/ Spark 2.4.3

Tested this problem on both local spark single machine instance and a Cloudera cluster and everything works fine.

#### set these in spark-env.sh

```py
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_PYTHON_DRIVER=python3
```

#### confirmed this in spark shell

```py
spark.version
2.4.3
sc.pythonExec
python3
SC.pythonVer
python3
```

#### running basic pandas_udf with apache arrow integration results in error

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))

@pandas_udf("id long, v double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def subtract_mean(pdf):
    # pdf is a pandas.DataFrame
    v = pdf.v
    return pdf.assign(v=v - v.mean())

df.groupby("id").apply(subtract_mean).show()
```

#### error on aws emr [doesn't error on cloudera and local machine]

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Anyone have an idea what is going on? some possible ideas ...

Could PYTHONPATH be causing a problem because I am not using `anaconda`?

Does it have to do with the Spark Version and Arrow Version?

This is the strangest thing because I am using the same versions across within all 3 platforms [local desktop, cloudera, emr] and only EMR is not working ...

**I logged into all 4 EMR EC2 data nodes and tested that I can import`pyarrow` and it works totally fine but not when trying to use it with `spark`**

```py
# test

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [20, np.nan, 2.5],'two': ['january', 'february', 'march'],'three': [True, False, True]},index=list('abc'))
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

Comment: I guess EMR spark use a different python interpreter. what's the result of echo $PYTHONPATH on that node?

Comment: it is empty when i echo

Comment: getting closer to finding the root cause @DennisLi ... when i run spark in local mode on EMR and run the ```pandas_udf``` code it works so it tells me something is wrong with the remaining nodes in the cluster not having the env vars mapped properly

Comment: have you set the PYSPARK_PYTHON on slaves. and make sure there's the pyarrow. or you can add a param to transfer Python env(zip file) to every nodes.

Comment: this cluster was created by someone else so i am not sure ... i have PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON set in the ```spark-env.sh``` on the master node

Comment: you need to set pyspark python on slaves

Comment: how is this accomplish in EMR? because in Cloudera all i ever have to do is set PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON in ```spark-env.sh``` on edge node

Comment: yes, you need to  copy it to all your slave nodes for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In EMR python3 is not resolved by default. You have to make it explicit. One way to do it is to pass a `config.json` file as you're creating the cluster. It's available in the `Edit software settings` section in AWS EMR UI. A sample json file looks something like this.

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark-env",
    "Configurations": [
      {
        "Classification": "export",
        "Properties": {
          "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Classification": "yarn-env",
    "Properties": {},
    "Configurations": [
      {
        "Classification": "export",
        "Properties": {
          "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Also you need to have the `pyarrow` module installed in all core nodes, not only in the master. For that you can use a bootstrap script while creating the cluster in AWS. Again, a sample bootstrap script can be as simple as something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python3 -m pip install pyarrow==0.13.0
```

Comment: thanks for the info ... yes ... bootstrap has been applied and is installed on all nodes ... same error ... will check the config file

Comment: this is the path where it is installed on every node ```/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages```

Comment: This is a working solution for us, we're using it against EMR 5.23.0. Let me know if it's working for you too.

Comment: won't be able to confirm in the next few days ... why are you using ```yarn-env```? i don't see any documentation on this

Comment: well, for spark that's optional. Here's the official doc: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-pyspark-python-3x/

Comment: this worked! specifically it was the way ```python``` was installing the packages ... the bootstrap was using the ```hadoop``` user via ```pip-3.6``` and installing under ```~/.local/lib/...``` which i think was causing problems with the ```ec2 linux``` preferences whereas ```root``` user installs under ```/usr/lib64/...``` ... thank you!!!

Comment: This did not work for me. When I run `pyspark` on the master, I can see it is being run with Python 3. I can also import pyarrow on any of the nodes. However, when I submit a job that uses pyarrow, I get `ImportError: PyArrow >= 0.8.0 must be installed; however, it was not found.`

Answer (score 3):

There are two options in your case:

One is to make sure the Python env is correct on every machines:

- set the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to your Python interpreter that has installed the third part module such as `pyarrow`. you can use `type -a python` to check how many python there is on your slave node.
- if the python interpreter path are all the same on every nodes, you can set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` in `spark-env.sh` then copy to every other nodes. read this for more: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/spark-standalone.html

Another option is to add argument on `spark-submit`:

- you have to package your extra module to a `zip` or `egg` file first.
- then type`spark-submit --py-files pyarrow.zip your_code.py`. in this way, spark will transport your module automatically to every other nodes.
  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: thank you ... this all makes sense ... i am familiar with ```--py-files``` and tried it with the zipped module and it does not work ... same error ... the ```spark-env.sh``` doesn't even exist on the slaves nodes so not sure how/where to copy what i have on the master ... my cluster manager is ```YARN```

Comment: if you wanna set spark en with EMR. you 'd better take a look at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html

Comment: `spark-submit --conf "spark.yarn.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=$PYSPARK_PYTHON"` try adding a conf in spark-submit like this.