# Missing Python dependency when submitting pyspark job to EMR using Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, airflow, amazon-emr

We're using a bootstrap script for installing python libraries on the EMR cluster nodes for our Spark jobs. The script looks something like this:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas==0.22.0 scikit-learn==0.21.0
```

Once the cluster is up, we use Airflow's `SparkSubmitHook` to submit jobs to EMR. We use [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-pyspark-python-3x/) configuration to bind pyspark to python3. Problem is, once in a while, when the job starts running, we get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'` error. One such stacktrace is like this one below:

```
return self.loads(obj)
 File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1565624418111_0001/container_1565624418111_0001_01_000033/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 577, in loads
   return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
```

This issue is sporadic in nature, so out of 10 job submissions it might be happening 2-3 times. We're using EMR 5.23.0. I've tried upgrading to 5.26.0 as well, but same issue persists.

If I go to the cluster nodes, and check for that 'missing' package, I can see it's already installed. So, clearly it's not the issue with bootstrap script. That leaves me quite confused, because I've no clue whatsoever on what's going on here. I'd guess that it's binding to a different python version when the job gets triggered from Airflow, but that's just a shot in the dark. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, the following snippet worked out fine as a bootstrap script. The commented out part was also previously included in our scipt, and it caused issues. After removing that portion everything seems to be working fine.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip==19.1.1 >> /tmp/out.log

wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/s/spatialindex-1.8.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm >> /tmp/out.log
sudo yum -y localinstall spatialindex-1.8.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm >> /tmp/out.log

sudo python3 -m pip install python-dateutil==2.8.0 pandas==0.22.0 pyarrow==0.13.0 scikit-learn==0.21.0 geopy==1.19.0 Shapely==1.6.4.post2 geohash2==1.1 boto3==1.9.183 rtree==0.8.3 geopandas==0.5.0 >> /tmp/out.log

# python3 -m pip install --user python-dateutil==2.8.0 pandas==0.22.0 pyarrow==0.13.0 geopy==1.19.0 Shapely==1.6.4.post2 geohash2==1.1 boto3==1.9.183
# python3 -m pip install --user scikit-learn==0.21.0
```

One note here, when a job get's submitted through airflow it runs as root user. So probably that's why the `--user` installation doesn't work. Because this scipt gets executed as user **hadoop** on each EMR node.

Answer (score 2):

similar case may for reference. not sure if it work for EMR
In hadoop case, the python environment and package should be installed under the user hadoop or spark.

if install python package in root or other user environment, similar case like you may happend.

So, try to install your package with same user name of `hadoop` or `spark`.

Update ===============================================

I used to install cloudear work bench which similar spark cloud environment. In that case, the distributed dependency also needed.

Here is the hyperlink
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/data-science-workbench/latest/topics/cdsw_pyspark.html#distributing_dependencies

The keys are:

- 1. install dependencies package in all cloud nodes.
- 2. set up the conda virtual environment
- 3. set up the pyspark or pyspark3 path environment.
- 4. deployment the yarn & spark configuration to gateway(the sparksubmit host, or airflow host).

Goodluck.

If you feel the answer helpful, pls vote up.

Comment: hmm, I think it's installed under hadoop user. Else it wouldn't have worked when we ran our jobs directly from the EMR master node, instead of the airflow vm. Also, it works 8 out of 10 times. So, there's an inconsistency there.

Comment: it was the complete opposite for me @Yong Wang ... only installing packages as sudo worked ... possible different versions of ec2 are the problem ... see post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315030/aws-emr-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyarrow/57408712?noredirect=1#comment101325251_57408712

Comment: actually 1 is taken care by bootstrap script. 2 brings in additional complexity, with little benefit, management is more involved, so we didn't go that route. 3 is done using the config params in EMR. Only 4 is a bit unknown, so need to explore on that area.

Answer (score 2):

One way to resolve your problem could be by changing the way you summit your job to the cluster :

- Package the code of the step to run (with its dependencies) on a a s3 bucket (using pipenv and pipfiles for example). The package would look like this :

```
<script_to_execute_package>.zip
|- <script_to_execute_main>.py
|-other step files.py
|- ...
|-scikit-learn
    |-scikit-learn files
    | ...
|-pandas
    |- pandas files
    |- ...
|-other packages
    |-other packages files
    |- ...
```

- Instead of using the SparkSubmitHook use a EmrAddStepsOperator (+Sensor +CreateJobFlowOperator). Run the step with your packaged Python code. 
  It would be something like this:

```
step_to_run = [
                {
                    'Name': 'your_step_name',
                    'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
                    'HadoopJarStep': {
                        'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                        'Args': ["spark-submit", "--master", "yarn", "--deploy-mode", "client", "--py-files", "s3://<script_to_execute_package>.zip", "/tmp/driver.py", "<script_to_execute_main>.py", "", "--arg_to_pass_1", "arg1", "--arg_to_pass_2", "arg2", ...]
                    }
                }
]

some_task = EmrAddStepsOperator(
                task_id='some_task',
                job_flow_id='the_previously_created_job_flow_id',
                aws_conn_id=aws_conn_id,
                steps=extract_check_args_spark_step,
                dag=dag
            )

            some_task_check = EmrStepSensor(
                task_id='task_check_extract_check',
                job_flow_id='the_previously_created_job_flow_id',
                step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('some_task', key='return_value')[0] }}",
                aws_conn_id=aws_conn_id,
                poke_interval=10,
                dag=dag
            )
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if you use LaunchClusterOperator in your DAG file, is to use the 
"cluster_overrides" property. Then you can just copy the configuration from [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-pyspark-python-3x/) Amazon page. So the result would look like this (mentioning "Configurations" twice is done intentionally):

```
   LaunchClusterOperator(dag=yourdag, param2="something", cluster_overrides={
       "Configurations": [
         {
           "Classification": "spark-env",
           "Configurations": [
             {
              "Classification": "export",
              "Properties": {"PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"} 
             }
            ]
         }
       ]
      }
     )
```

Comment: If you look at the question, I've mentioned this config. This actually didn't help solving the issue, because problem was in the bootstrap script.