# How to set Jupyter notebook to Python3 instead of Python2.7 in AWS EMR

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am spinning up an EMR in AWS. The difficulty arises when using Jupyter to import associated Python modules. I have a shell script that executes when the EMR starts and imports Python modules.

The notebook is set to run using the PySpark Kernel.

I believe the problem is that the Jupyter notebook is not pointed to the correct Python in EMR. The methods I have used to set the notebook to the correct version do not seem to work.

I have set the following configurations. I have tried changing python to python3.6 and python3.

```
Configurations=[{
    "Classification": "spark-env",
    "Properties": {},
    "Configurations": [{
        "Classification": "export",
        "Properties": {
            "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "python",
            "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON": "python",
            "SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV": "python"
        }
    }]
```

I am certain that my shell script is importing the modules because when I run the following on the EMR command line (via SSH) it works:

```
python3.6
import boto3
```

However when I run the following, it does not work:

```
python
import boto3
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named boto3

When I run the following command in Jupyter I get the output below:

```
import sys
import os

print(sys.version)
```

2.7.16 (default, Jul 19 2019, 22:59:28) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]

```
#!/bin/bash
alias python=python3.6
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="python"
export SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV="python"
sudo python3 -m pip install boto3
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas
sudo python3 -m pip install pymysql
sudo python3 -m pip install xlrd
sudo python3 -m pip install pymssql
```

When I attempt to import boto3 I get an error message using Jupyter:

No module named boto3
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: No module named boto3

Comment: please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315030/aws-emr-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyarrow/57408712?noredirect=1#comment101325251_57408712

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Python3 with EMR notebooks, the recommended way is to use pyspark kernel and configure Spark to use Python3 within the notebook as,

```
%%configure -f {"conf":{ "spark.pyspark.python": "python3" }}
```

Note that,

- Any on cluster configuration related to PYSPARK_PYTHON or PYSPARK_PYTHON_DRIVER is overridden by EMR notebook configuration. The only way to configure for Python3 is from within the notebook as mentioned above.
- pyspark3 kernel is deprecated for Livy 4.0+, and henceforth pyspark kernel is recommended to be used for both Python2 and Python3 by configuring spark.pyspark.python accordingly.
- If you want to install additional Python dependencies which are not already present on the cluster, you can use [notebook-scoped libraries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-scoped-libraries.html). It works for both Python2 as well as Python3.

Comment: This is the solution that I am currently employing. Thank you for answering it.

Comment: It seems odd though. Setting the configurations when launching EMR used to work.            "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "python",
            "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON": "python",
            "SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV": "python"