# How can I install a module to a specific Jupyter kernel without use of ! or terminal?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am using JupyterHub on an EMR and Pandas is not installed on the PySpark or PySpark3 kernels. These kernels also disallow use of `!`. I have tried to install using

```
import pip
pip.main(['install','pandas])
```

But this raises `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

When I open the terminal kernel, pandas is already installed.

Please let me know if there are other ways to install to a specific kernel.

Comment: you should apply a bootstrap .py script (containing all your modules) when creating the emr cluster because all modules need to be installed on every node (if you intend to use them with spark)

Comment: I have added a bootstrap with pandas, but it does not show up in the PySpark or PySpark3 kernel; it only shows up in the Python kernel

Comment: how are you installing in the bootstrap? can you paste the command?

Comment: I have the shebang and then the following command: `sudo pip install scipy scikit-learn pandas pyarrow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced similar problems and this resolved my situation

```
#bootstrap
sudo python3 -m pip install <packages>
```

```
# set in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh or use the config.json template for EMR
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
```

Reference:
[AWS EMR - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315030/aws-emr-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyarrow/57408712?noredirect=1#comment101325251_57408712)

Comment: Wow, turns out you were right! It was a Python 2 vs 3 issue.

Comment: sudo install is usually dangerous.