# No module named 'pyspark' when running Jupyter notebook inside EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am (very) new to AWS and Spark in general, and I'm trying to run a notebook instance in Amazon EMR. When I try to import pyspark to start a session and load data from s3, I get the error No module named 'pyspark'. The cluster I created had the Spark option filled, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed the python package, e.g. `pip install pyspark` ?

Comment: You can follow the steps [here](https://www.sicara.ai/blog/2017-05-02-get-started-pyspark-jupyter-notebook-3-minutes) to configure it

Comment: Thanks for the comments and sorry I took so long to reply. This solution works for local, but my problem is with the notebook instance generated and managed by AWS in EMR module. Any thoughts on how to solve this in a EMR notebook?

Comment: Have you tried https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-pyspark-python-3x/ ?

Comment: I did try the option "on a new cluster". If I am not mistaken, I should cp/paste that code inside the "edit software settings", which I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me was to change the notebook kernel to the PySpark kernel, then changing the bootstrap action to install packages (in python version3.6) that are not by default in the pyspark kernel:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python3.6 -m pip install numpy \
    matplotlib \
    pandas \
    seaborn \
    pyspark
```

Apparently by default it installs to python 2.7.16, so it outputs no error message but you can't import the modules because the spark env uses Python 2.7.16.

Comment: You can pass a config while launching the cluster to force it to use Python 3. To know how to go about it, please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57408712/4245859

Comment: This problem really troubles me, on the one hand, you can change to spark kernel very easily, but on the other hand when converting to python file and trying to run using spark-submit you encounter problem due to differences between kernel. What is the right way to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can open jupyter lab notebook and select new spark notebook from there.
This will initiate the spark context automatically for you.

[image]

Or you can open Jupyter notebook and load spark app by `%%spark`

[image]

Comment: The former worked for me (selecting PySpark notebook type); the spark magic syntax from a regular Jupyter notebook did not.

Answer (score 0):

You Could try  using the findspark library.
Could pip install findspark and below code in your jupyter.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

%load_ext sparksql_magic
%config SparkSql.limit=200
```

Comment: Could you please format your answer and check the orthography?