# How to install boto3 onto an EMR cluster for use with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I'm having issues getting boto3 installed on EMR. Here is the bootstrap script I'm currently using:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Install Python 3 kernel
sudo yum install python3
sudo yum install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install -U boto3
```

I checked the logs and it says that boto3 was successfully installed, but when I try to import it in a Jupyter notebook I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

Comment: I think bootstrap script is a cleaner approach for installing 3rd party dependencies. The issue you're facing is most likely due to jupyter using a different kernel. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57408712/4245859

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. Launch a notebook with the pyspark kernel and run this:

```
sc.install_pypi_package(“boto3”)
```